# Parcel command not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

In my project, I use Parcel to bundle everything. Now, I am at the point where I need to deploy my app.
I clone my git repo with my React app and I put in the Node server.

I tried every command possible to install parcel, but I always get the following error :

```
> pp-react@0.1.0 build /home/volodymk/react
> parcel build index.html

sh: parcel: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! pp-react@0.1.0 build: `parcel build index.html`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pp-react@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/volodymk/.npm/_logs/2020-01-12T19_26_22_634Z-debug.log
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To run any installed node package (not just Parcel), use `npx`, the utility command shipped with npm. It executes packages that come with a runtime command in your `node_modules/packagename/.bin` directories.

As in `npx parcel build index.html`

More information available in [the npx readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx).

Comment: Adding npx to the parcel build command fixed the issue for me :)